# How to use a column's attribute for grouping but omit it on response?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have this record interface

```java
public interface EmployeesRecord {
    String getName();
    String getDepartment();
    String getEmail();
}
```

That is used to fetch the 3-columns rows from a repository query as a list

and I have created a DTO to serve as a response `Map<String, List<EmployeesRecord>>` where the string is using one of the columns, as a key, to group the results.

```java
public record EmployeesDto(Map<String, List<EmployeesRecord>> employeesRecordList) {

    public static EmployeesDto from(List<EmployeesRecord> data) {

        Map<String, List<EmployeesRecord>> mappedEmployees =
                data.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(EmployeesRecord::getDepartment));

        return new EmployeesDto(mappedEmployees);
    }
}
```

**My question is after I use the attribute as a key, how do I remove it from the objects responses?**

The current response:

```json
{
    "employeesRecordList": {
        "finance": [
            {
                "name": "Jerry Doe",
                "department": "finance",
                "email": "jerry@corp.co"
            },
            ...
            {
                "name": "Jimmy Doe",
                "department": "finance",
                "email": "jimmy@corp.co"
            }
        ],
        ...
        "engineering": [
            {
                "name": "Joe Doe",
                "department": "engineering",
                "email": "joe@corp.co"
            },
            ...
            {
                "name": "Joana Doe",
                "department": "engineering",
                "email": "joana@corp.co"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The desired response is the same minus the "department" in the body:

```json
{
    "employeesRecordList": {
        "finance": [
            {
                "name": "Jerry Doe",
                "email": "jerry@corp.co"
            },
            ...
            {
                "name": "Jimmy Doe",
                "email": "jimmy@corp.co"
            }
        ],
        ...
        "engineering": [
            {
                "name": "Joe Doe",
                "email": "joe@corp.co"
            },
            ...
            {
                "name": "Joana Doe",
                "email": "joana@corp.co"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Your interface `EmployeesRecord` has that field (so to speak). Are you sure you need to remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to put `@JsonIgnore` above `String getDepartment();`

---

Another solution would be creating a class containing only `name` and `email` attributes.

```java
public class EmployeesNameAndEmail {
  public String name;
  public String email;

  public EmployeesNameAndEmail(EmployeesRecord employeesRecord) {
    name = employeesRecord.getName();
    email = employeesRecord.getEmail();
  }
}
```

Then, the additional mapping should be added after the grouping:

```java
Map<String, List<EmployeesNameAndEmail>> mappedEmployees =
    data.stream().collect(
      Collectors.groupingBy(
            EmployeesRecord::getDepartment,
            Collectors.mapping(EmployeesNameAndEmail::new,Collectors.toList())));
```